# How to do comparison and adding AtomicInteger

Tags: concurrency, atomic, java.util.concurrent, atomicinteger

There is such **synchronized** function:

```
private int balance;


//...

public synchronized void executeRequest(Request request) {

        switch (request.getType()) {
            case CREDIT:
                if(balance >= request.getAmount()) {
                    balance -= request.getAmount();
                    System.out.printf(SUCCESS,
                            request,
                            Thread.currentThread().getName(),
                            balance);
                } else {
                    System.out.printf(FAILURE,
                                    request,
                                    Thread.currentThread().getName(),
                                    balance);
                }

                break;
            case REPAYMENT:
                balance += request.getAmount();
                System.out.printf(SUCCESS,
                        request,
                        Thread.currentThread().getName(),
                        balance);
                break;

        }
    }
```

I need to rewrite it by using AtomicInteger for **balance** parameter.

I can't come up with how to do two actions atomically:

1. balance >= request.getAmount()
2. balance -= request.getAmount();

I try to rewrite CREDIT operation like that:

```
private void credit(int amount, String request) {
        int oldValue;
        int newValue;
        do {
            oldValue = balance.get();
            newValue = oldValue - amount;
            if (oldValue >= amount) {
                System.out.printf(SUCCESS,
                        request,
                        Thread.currentThread().getName(),
                        balance);
            } else {
                System.out.printf(FAILURE,
                        request,
                        Thread.currentThread().getName(),
                        balance);
            }
        } while (!balance.compareAndSet(oldValue, newValue));
    }
```

But it won't work, because there's no guarantee that `oldValue >= amount` will be true when we try to compute `!balance.compareAndSet(oldValue, newValue)` again.

Have you any idea how to rewrite the first method with AtomicInteger?

Comment: I don't understand your concern.  The code looks fine to me, except that when `balance < amount` it will print failure but then go ahead and deduct `amount` anyway, leaving a negative balance.  It's not clear if that's what you intend.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a such decision. What do you think about it?

```
private void credit(int amount, String request) {
        int oldValue;
        int newValue;
        while (true) {
            oldValue = balance.get();
            newValue = oldValue - amount;
            if (oldValue >= amount && balance.compareAndSet(oldValue, newValue)) {
                System.out.printf(SUCCESS,
                        request,
                        Thread.currentThread().getName(),
                        newValue);
                break;
            } else if (oldValue < amount) {
                System.out.printf(FAILURE,
                        request,
                        Thread.currentThread().getName(),
                        oldValue);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This also looks fine, and now it is clear that if `balance < amount` the balance will not be updated.